# modal with PHP script that will edit the information of the specific data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

How can I use modal to edit the specific data. For example, when I click the button beside the data, it will get the `id` of it and a modal will appear with all of the information of that specific data?

Below is an example of modal that i will use but only plain modal without php codes.

```
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-md" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can use data-* attributes to store any required info you may need, eg, your element ID. Then, you can bind a click event to your button to manually show your modal box and make and ajax request to retrieve entire html to display an edit form. Or you can attach all your logic to "show" event on bootstrap modal box. Eg: `$('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) { 
alert('modal shown')
})`

Comment: Your question should be more specific!!

Answer (score 0):

You better use ajax for this case

The steps for your need are:
 1. sent the parameter id with ajax data.
 2. select data with the query an return with JSON in file that you mention in ajax url.
 3. The last, showing modal with the JSON data that you have made.

This is basic about ajax http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_ajax.asp